# libvips FFI use on Windows PHP cannot find glib functions

Tags: php, windows, ffi, glib, vips

I am attempting to use the libvips package on Windows 11.

I have installed the composer package `"jcupitt/vips": "2.0.0"`

My local PHP setup is laragon, and I have enabled the FFI extension for PHP.

I have installed libvips binary for Windows and added it to the path. It works when I call it from the command line directly. Example: `vips invert input.png output.png`

When running the following file (which uses FFI):

```
<?php
require dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Jcupitt\Vips;

// fast thumbnail generator
$image = Vips\Image::thumbnail('example-rug.jpg', 128);
$image->writeToFile('tiny.jpg');
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught FFI\Exception: Failed resolving C function
> 'g_malloc' in
> C:\laragon\www\efc\rugz\vendor\jcupitt\vips\src\Config.php:773 Stack
> trace:
> #0 C:\laragon\www\efc\rugz\vendor\jcupitt\vips\src\Config.php(773): FFI::cdef('// we need the ...', 'libvips-42.dll')
> #1 C:\laragon\www\efc\rugz\vendor\jcupitt\vips\src\Config.php(195): Jcupitt\Vips\Config::init()
> #2 C:\laragon\www\efc\rugz\vendor\jcupitt\vips\src\Config.php(259): Jcupitt\Vips\Config::ffi()
> #3 C:\laragon\www\efc\rugz\vendor\jcupitt\vips\src\Image.php(712): Jcupitt\Vips\Config::filenameGetFilename('..\example-rug....')
> #4 C:\laragon\www\efc\rugz\src\examples\bench.php(8): Jcupitt\Vips\Image::newFromFile('..\example-rug....', Array)
> #5 {main}
>
> Next FFI\Exception: Failed resolving C function 'g_free' in
> C:\laragon\www\efc\rugz\vendor\jcupitt\vips\src\Config.php:773 Stack
> trace:
> #0 C:\laragon\www\efc\rugz\vendor\jcupitt\vips\src\Config.php(773): FFI::cdef('// we need the ...', 'libvips-42.dll')
> #1 C:\laragon\www\efc\rugz\vendor\jcupitt\vips\src\Config.php in C:\laragon\www\efc\rugz\vendor\jcupitt\vips\src\Config.php on line 773

All I could think is that these are 2 glib functions and maybe I do not have the glib dll file?

I checked the vips bin folder, and `libglib-2.0-0.dll` is found there. This is in the same bin folder, so it should be found at the path if necessary.

I know this is being pulled in via the `libvips-42.dll`, because if I rename `libglib-2.0-0.dll` file, the FFI output becomes:

> Fatal error: Uncaught FFI\Exception: Failed loading 'libvips-42.dll'

The last bit of info I can provide is that the offending portion of the command fed to FFI appears to be:

```
void* g_malloc (size_t size);
void g_free (void* data);
```

Comment: You need to get the libvips bin area on the PATH used by your web server. You might need to dig into the config a bit. Use phpinfo() to verify that your scripts are seeing the correct value.

Comment: @jcupitt - I can confirm from phpinfo that the vips bin folder is first in the `Path => C:\vips\vips-dev-8.12\bin;` It does find the vips program, but it seemingly fails to understand `g_malloc` and `g_free` commands in FFI. 
It could definitely still be a config issue, just not sure what other dependencies I may be missing? Or if this is potentially a bug in the latest windows binaries?

Comment: It could perhaps be a php-vips bug, I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/libvips/php-vips/issues/144 let's move discussion to github (stackoverflow is not great for debugging things like this).

Answer (score 0):

Guess `libvips-42.dll` has to be manually provided:
https://github.com/libvips/build-win64-mxe/releases

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have downloaded the binary `vips-dev-w64-all-8.12.2.zip` and added it to my PATH in windows. I can successfully call vips from cmd. The script using FFI also successfully finds the `libvips-42.dll` file, it just pukes when I hits a glib statement

Comment: @KeithBauer You may need just the same version used at build time. There's no `ldd` on Windows, but likely other tools to inspect DLL (sorry but I've forgot the name).

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in v2.0.3:

https://github.com/libvips/php-vips/pull/146

Just update and it'll work (hopefully).